# Why is errno set to 22: mq_open() POSIX

Tags: c, posix, message-queue

---

Im receiving errno 22 when trying to create a message_queue in POSIX with C.
As far as I can tell, by comparing to example code available on the web, I've set the parameters correctly.

Here is a snippet:

```
    int open_flags;
    mqd_t mqfd;
    int bytes_per_msg;
    struct mq_attr attr;
    unsigned int* msgbuff;

    printf("from 1 to 400, what is N? : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    bytes_per_msg = (n + 1) * (sizeof(unsigned int));
    msgbuff = (unsigned int*)malloc(bytes_per_msg);

    open_flags = O_CREAT|O_RDWR;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = n;
    attr.mq_msgsize = bytes_per_msg;
    attr.mq_flags   = 0;


    mqfd = mq_open("/myqueue", open_flags, 0666, &attr);

    if(mqfd == -1){
        printf("queue creation failed, ERRNO: %d\n",errno);
    }
```

EDIT: My apologies for not being more clear. Errno 22 is INVALID ARGUMENT.
--The meanings of the error numbers can be found on errno.h

Comment: Check what the errno refers to with `perror()`.

Comment: You can lookup what the errno means on errno.h.
using perror leads to the same conclusion: error 22: Invalid Argument>
Im trying to figure out what is invalid with my argument.
I don't remember where I found errno without perror @WilliamPursell

Comment: @Chris: we cannot look at `errno.h` on your machine — and nothing in POSIX says 'errno 22 shall be EINVAL — invalid argument'.  Therefore, you have to translate for us; you have access to your machine and can do that.

Comment: So errno.h can be different from machine to machine? This is something that I also wasn't aware of. Every webpage I've found that shows the contents of errno.h is the same.

Comment: `errno.h` can be different on different operating systems. It is probably different on SunOS4/Sparc than on Linux/x86-64 and IIRC it is different on Linux/ARM and on Linux/x86-64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using [mq_open(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_open.3.html) on Linux, and `errno` getting `EINVAL`. According to the documentation it may happen when:

> name doesn't follow the format in mq_overview(7).

or

> O_CREAT was specified in oflag, and attr was not NULL, but
> attr->mq_maxmsg or attr->mq_msqsize was invalid.  Both of
> these fields must be greater than zero.  In a process that is
> unprivileged (does not have the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability),
> attr->mq_maxmsg must be less than or equal to the msg_max
> limit, and attr->mq_msgsize must be less than or equal to the
> msgsize_max limit.  In addition, even in a privileged process,
> attr->mq_maxmsg cannot exceed the HARD_MAX limit.  (See
> mq_overview(7) for details of these limits.)

So you should also read [mq_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html)

Next time, use [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) on error cases. Notice that POSIX [errno.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/errno.h.html) specification does not assign numerical values to error numbers like `EINVAL` (and that is on purpose, several POSIX compliant systems could have different numbers).

BTW, you should always check the return value of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html), in your case:

```
printf("from 1 to 400, what is N? : \n");
n= 0;
if (scanf("%d", &n)<1 || n<=0 || n>400) { 
  fprintf(stderr, "bad number (n=%d)\n", n);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

well for me it was a missing forward slash "/" in name which caused errno 22.